# visualize two columns in the same data set

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, plotly, data-visualization

[image]

I am trying to group and sort four columns, count values and chart them in the same bar graph to see the trend how the count has changed.

[image]

```
Year  Month  Bl_year  Month
2018  Jan     2019     Jan 
2018  Feb     2018     Mar
2018  Dec     2020     Dec 
2019  Apr     2019     Sep  
2020  Nov     2020     Dec 
2019  Sep     2018     Jan
```

I tried to group and sort first and counting values first by the year and then next by the month.

```
df_Activity_count = df.sort_values(['year','month'],ascending = True).groupby('month')
df_Activity_count_BL = df.sort_values(['BL year','BL month'],ascending = True).groupby('BL month')
```

Now I am trying to compare these two in the same bar. Can someone please help.

Comment: Hi Sheldore, Thanks for your help. Did accept your answer. I voted it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to pass `ax` to your plot command:

```
df_Activity_count = df.sort_values(['year','month'],ascending = True).groupby('month')
df_Activity_count_BL = df.sort_values(['BL year','BL month'],ascending = True).groupby('BL month')

ax = df_Activity_count.years.value_counts().unstack(0).plot.bar()
df_Activity_count_BL['BL year'].value_counts().unstack(0).plot.bar(ax=ax)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged `matplotlib`, I will chip in a solution using `pyplot`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create an axis object
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Define dataframes
df_Activity_count = df.sort_values(['year','month'],ascending = True).groupby('month')
df_Activity_count_BL = df.sort_values(['BL year','BL month'],ascending = True).groupby('BL month')

# Plot using the axis object ax defined above
df_Activity_count['year'].value_counts().unstack(0).plot.bar(ax=ax)
df_Activity_count_BL['BL year'].value_counts().unstack(0).plot.bar(ax=ax)
```

Comment: both the codes are giving me the same solution. Thanks a lot for your solutions learned something new today. But looking for something like. I want to compare the count of Apr 2019 BL Month to April Month next to each other, two bar graphs next to each other so, I can visualize the variance